# iPhone app distribution: What name will appear on the AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store, distribution

Is there a way to change the name that displays on the AppStore, rather than the name associated with the credit card/apple ID associated with the developer programme?

For example, if my name on my credit card was **foo**, and the name on the apple ID was **foo**, but I actually want the name displayed on the AppStore (i.e. next to my App's name and details) to be **bar**.

BTW: The programme is individual.

Many thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will specify this in iTunes Connect when you are signing up for distribution.

Comment: So, let's say I've bought the iPhone Developer Programme (which I haven't yet). I use my mothers name and Apple ID for the credit card and suchlike. Will my mother's name be the name that's used? Or is there another step with allows me to define my name that's used for distribution?

Comment: There will be another step that allows you to define your name that's used for distribution.